# Best practice to show data in HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to show more than 50k lines in a HTML table but for some reason it takes so much time to show (around 60 seconds), what's the best practice to load data into HTML tables?
I am using this code:

```
    $('#entities_panel_gridlist').empty();
    $('#entities_panel_gridlist').append("<table id='entities_list' width='100%'><tr class='entities_gridlist_heading'><th width='59%'>Name</th><th width='40%'>Hash</th></tr></table>");
    var len = myTable.length
    for (var i=0; i < len; i++) {
        let name = myTable[i][0];
        let hash = myTable[i][1];

        console.log(i)

        $('#entities_list').append('<tr class="rows"><td>'+ name +'</td><td>'+ hash +'</td></tr>');
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This: "_what's the best practice to load data into HTML tables?_" - Start by not loading 50k rows of date into an HTML table. Do the same thing MS Exel does, or Google Sheets does; namely only present the amount of information consumable by the human. Stop focusing on what the machine can or cannot do with 50k rows. The view port is all you have to fill - so fill that much. Then determine either an infinite scroll or pagination strategy to be used for displaying a view port of data at a time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Randy but my project really requires all of the data being showed at once.

Comment: I realize I won't convince you that you can sort, pare and tailor your data on the server. Your use case is flawed you need all 50k rows in a browser window. If this is some automated processing mechanism for which there is not human involved, then do it with a headless browser and  _really, really_ speed it up. Otherwise, a human can only see what's on the screen - putting 49,975 rows out of view does no one any good. OK, _but how would we sort them_, _we can't change the server_, etc. etc. I get it. Good luck to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save some rendering resources by collecting the markup in a variable and append it afterwards.

```
 $('#entities_panel_gridlist').empty();  
 $('#entities_panel_gridlist').append("<table id='entities_list' width='100%'><tr class='entities_gridlist_heading'><th width='59%'>Name</th><th width='40%'>Hash</th></tr></table>"); 
 var len = myTable.length;
 var markup = '';
 for (var i=0; i < len; i++) { 
   let name = myTable[i][0]; 
   let hash = myTable[i][1]; 
   var markup += '<tr class="rows"><td>'+ name +'</td><td>'+ hash +'</td></tr>';
 }
 $('#entities_list').append(markup);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Time decreased from 60 seconds to 6 seconds but it is still somehow slow, is there anything better than I could do to speed it up a little bit more? Or maybe a way to load it async so the UI doesn't stuck.

Comment: @HassoN the only two ways to speed it up even more are : 1. buy a faster computer 2. display less data

Comment: Please note that a string in ECMA 2016 is limited to 1 GB but for backwards compatibility it is important to limit a string to 256 MB. With 50K lines this will not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

For big volumes, add more **sorting and search tools**!

50k lines at once is way too much. A user should only need the first lines to figure out what the whole table content looks like.

Look for more advanced table tools, such as pagination or search. Here is what the Material Angular table pagination looks like: https://stackblitz.com/angular/byrxvplrqxv?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-pagination-example.ts